# Clarification regarding methods being used outside a contract in interface

Tags: java, interface

in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

may i now how it was possible to use the to toString Method despite not being stated in the contract? Was it because it was in public so any method that declared public could be used anyway?.

Comment: thanks for the replies! Those saved me alot of time searching for answer i wish i could upvote now but it looks like i cannot yet. All replies are good i feel guilty marking one as best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, every class inherits from [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), and [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is part of the `Object`'s contract.

Thus, any Java object has a `toString()` method. Additionally, since `toString()` is non-`final`, any class can choose to provide its own implementation of the method.

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` is defined in the `Object` class. And every other class is an `Object`. You will always be implicitly extending the Object class. So, you can call any method of the Object class (`hashCode(),toString(), wait()` etc) on your instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is inherited by the java's super class `Object`,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Along with the following

```
clone()
boolean equals(Object obj)
protected void  finalize()
Class<?>    getClass()
int hashCode()
void    notify()
void    notifyAll()
void    wait()
void    wait(long timeout)
void    wait(long timeout, int nanos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interface defines a contract for **minimum** service agreement - **any** extra functionality can be added at any time but it will not be part of the contract.